# For some reason Visual Studio thinks that handled exceptions was unhandled

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

I have the follow code part

```
            try
            {
                ThreadPool.BindHandle(_client.Client.Handle);
            }
            catch (ApplicationException)
            {
            }
```

Visual studio still stops in line `ThreadPool.BindHandle(_client.Client.Handle);` with message that ApplicationException was unhandled in code. Why unhandled when it is handled? Why does VS stops there? (VS 2015/2013/2015).

Comment: In the exception settings is it checked to stop at ApplicationException? ApplicationException btw differentiates between exceptions defined by applications versus exceptions defined by the system.

Comment: @ ntoh No! all exceptions types are unchecked

Comment: `ThreadPool.BindHandle(((System.Net.Sockets)something).Handle)` will use the `ThreadPool.BindHandle(IntPtr)` version, which is depricated

Comment: there is a safe socket handle implementation in Mono. I don't know if I would go that far, but [here it is](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/SafeSocketHandle.cs)

Comment: Surely because the exception was *actually* raised on another thread.  That happens when you use BindHandle.  If the Exception Assistant does not help for some reason then use the debugger's Debug > Windows > Threads and Call Stack window to find the failing code back.  Turning off Just My Code would be wise as well.  Post the stack trace you see, something you should always do when you ask a question about an exception btw.